# Import pygame from file (No install)

Tags: python, import, pygame

I'm writing a library for Python, and it uses Pygame. To make it more mobile and user-friendly, I want to be able to import Pygame like you can import jQuery in JavaScript/ HTML. I have the Pygame zip file, but I have not been able to find any sort of help. Here's what I'm talking about, but written in HTML:

```
<script src="example.js"></script>
```

In python, it should look something like

```
import Pygame
```

Please try to explain this in beginner language - as simple as possible, and if possible - with examples.

Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

You have first to uncompress the zip-archive file.
Then, make sure you have a folder called `Pygame` with a file `__init__.py`.
Finally, you can import it with `import Pygame` after you moved it in the `site-packages` folder, or you can import it using the following code :

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Path/to/the/directory/containing/the/Pygame/folder')
import Pygame
```

The explanation is that Python looks for the modules you want to import only in the folders in the `sys.path` list (you can display it and see that it contains the path of `site-packages`). Thus, if the module is not in a standard location, you have to add its path to this list.

EDIT: Sorry, my bad, I thought it was possible to run Pygame without any install. But, after I looked in the downloaded file, it requires installation. I think this question is a duplicate of [Using Pygame without installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368246/using-pygame-without-installing)

Comment: I tried 'import sys
sys.path.append('pygame-1.9.1release\pygame-1.9.1release\lib\__init__.py')
import pygame' and it didn't work, it threw the error "No module named pygame"

Comment: there are proper line breaks, btw. I didnt know how to do that in a comment

Comment: You cannot break lines in a comment. You have to append the path of the folder that _contains_ the Pygame folder. And you should remove the 'dll' tag. If you want to have the exact text you typed displayed, surround it with backticks : `

Comment: there is no "Pygame" folder, I have a folder named Pygame-1.9-release and inside that is the lib folder, which has an init inside of it. I appended the containing folder (lib) and imported pygame but still got the error

Comment: I don't really understand the answer my question is a 'duplicate' of

Comment: Because in fine you want to use pygame without installing it.